# How can I improve the performance of RecyclerView and Firebase search?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I view the data that the user queries through an edittext via Firebase database in the application with `RecyclerView`. My problem is. If the queried text is too much in the database (for example: 1000+), the application may crash. However, if the queried text is less in the database (for example: less than 100), there is no problem and the code works fine. I want to know why this is the problem and I am looking for an answer. I've seen records that the Logcat has overloaded the CPU. I think this problem occurs when I want to show the results from the database with an adapter in practice. I tried using background threads but it didn't work or I used it in the wrong place. I'd appreciate it if you helped. What should I investigate and find out if I can solve this problem? Sorry for my bad English.

> My Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<User> options;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, NameViewHolder> adapter;
    Query firebaseSearchQuery;
    RecyclerView Search_Contact_List;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("MyDatabase");

Search_Contact_List = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Search_Contact_List);
        Search_Contact_List.setHasFixedSize(true);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getBaseContext(),1);
        Search_Contact_List.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

        firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("phone").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<User>()
                .setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery,User.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, NameViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NameViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final User model) {

                holder.result_name.setText(model.getName());
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public NameViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

                View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.list_layout,parent,false);
                return new NameViewHolder(itemView);
            }

        };
    setCategory() ;
    }

private void setCategory() {

        adapter.startListening();
        Search_Contact_List.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

> User.java:

```
public class User {

    public String name;
    public String phone;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String name, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }
}
```

> NameViewHolder.java:

```
public class NameViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView result_name;

    public NameViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        result_name = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.Search_Result_Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `activity_main.xml`? I'm curious if your RecyclerView is using `wrap_content` for one of its dimensions.

Comment: Have you tried to implement some kind of paging system yet? You could/should only show the top 12 results in your recyclerView at start. I would also block the search if the user enters less than 3 characters to avoid unnecessary return values.

Comment: If it is less than 10 characters, it prevents querying. I shared some of the codes. My problem is just performance. When I want to list the data from the database, the application can crash, but it runs smoothly if the data is low.

Comment: You could try to add `.limitToFirst(50);` to your `firebaseSearchQuery`? You shouldn't display more than 20 items in your RecyclerView in one shot in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I did as you said. At first I limited the data and then I used paging. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the queried text is too much in the database (for example 1000+)

Getting 1000+ objects at once is pretty much. Besides the fact that no users will ever interact will all those objects, in my opinion, is a waste of bandwidth, resources, and money. If you store much data within your objects, you'll also get an [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).

So the best practice, in this case, is to reduce the number of objects that you get in a single query. As the other developers recommended you, you should get data in smaller chunks. This practice is called [pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D+pagination) and it's been discussed quite a few times before here on StackOverflow.
I recommend you have a look at some of these questions and give it a try ;)